# Will simplify inserts into tables with auto-generated primary keys?

Tags: database, scala, slick-2.0

In Slick 1.x, inserting into a table with an auto generated primary key was kind of complicated: you had to manually create a table projection that omitted the pk for insert purposes. It looks like Slick 2.x will fix this problem:

> Soft inserts are now the default, i.e. AutoInc columns are automatically skipped when inserting with +=, ++=, insert and insertAll. This means that you no longer need separate projections (without the primary key) for inserts.

However the 2.x docs must not be updated:

> While some database systems allow inserting proper values into AutoInc columns or inserting None to get a created value, most databases forbid this behaviour, so you have to make sure to omit these columns. Slick does not yet have a feature to do this automatically but it is planned for a future release. For now, you have to use a query with a custom projection which does not include the AutoInc column

Does anyone know the new 2.0 syntax for doing an insert into a table with AutoInc and get the generated key back?

Comment: `val generatedId = (suppliers returning suppliers.map(_.id)) += (0, "supplier a")` // the 0 is a place holder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for inserts is the same as in 1.0, only that now autoinc columns are automatically ignored. So there is a semantic change in what `.insert` does. If you want the old behavior (where they are included) you have to call `.forceInsert`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  You can retrieve the generated value like this:

  case class Employee( empName: String,empType: String, empId: Int = 0)
        class Employees(tag: Tag) extends Table[Employee](tag, "emp") {
          def empId = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
          def empName = column[String]("name", O DBType ("VARCHAR(100)"))
          def empType = column[String]("type")
          def * = (empName, empType, empId) <> (Employee.tupled, Employee.unapply)
        }
        val employees = TableQuery[Employees]
        val myInsert = employees.map(e => (e.empName, e.empType)) returning employees.map(_.empId) 
        val autoGenratedKey = myInsert.insert("satendra", "permanent")
```